# How to recommend books for a user based on other users who bought and rate the books?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am working on a simple recommendation engine using PHP and MongoDB. I am trying to recommend books for a user based on what other users bought. I have these data and I would like to count how many books each user has in common with the new user.

The collection fields are :

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474a61307ad40ea8003587"),
"userid" : "1",
"bookid" : "100",
"rate" : 4
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474aa9307ad40ea8003588"),
"userid" : "2",
"bookid" : "100",
"rate" : 4
}

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474ab0307ad40ea8003589"),
"userid" : "1",
"bookid" : "110",
"rate" : 4
}

/* 4 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474ad7307ad40ea800358a"),
"userid" : "2",
"bookid" : "110",
"rate" : 3
}

/* 5 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474adc307ad40ea800358b"),
"userid" : "3",
"bookid" : "100",
"rate" : 5
}

/* 6 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474af4307ad40ea800358d"),
"userid" : "3",
"bookid" : "120",
"rate" : 4
}

 /* 7 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474b36307ad40ea8003592"),
"userid" : "2",
"bookid" : "120",
"rate" : 5
}

/* 8 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58474b43307ad40ea8003593"),
"userid" : "4",
"bookid" : "100",
"rate" : 2
}
```

I tried alot to find the solution but no luck. Any help appreciated :)

Edited:
I tried this code but it does not work

```
$out = $purchase->find(["userid"=>"1"]);
foreach($out as $a){
$pipeline = array(
        array('$match' => array('bookid' => $a['bookid'])),
        array('$group' => array('_id' => '$userid',
             'count' => array('$sum' => 1)),
            ),
);
$result = $Ratingscollection->aggregate($pipeline);
    foreach ($result as $aa){
        echo $aa["_id"]."&nbsp";
        echo $aa['count']."</br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your problem. You could try this. First store the bookid of the new user in a variable named as **newUserBookId** and suppose in our case it is 100.

Now  Run the following Query-

```
> var newUserBookId ="100";
> db.xx.aggregate([{ $match: { "bookid": newUserBookId } },{$group : {"_id" : "$bookid", num_of_users: {$sum : 1}}}]);
```

Hoping this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: How can I implement this in PHP?

Comment: $m = new MongoClient("localhost"); // or URL og you mongoserver
$c = $m->selectDB("database_name")->selectCollection("collection_name");

Comment: I have not much hands on PHP

Comment: Have you fired the query in core mongo terminal ? I am sure It will work.

Comment: In mongo terminal, it works but it does  not work with PHP:(